# aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq

Tags: docker, rust, alpine-linux

when I build the rust app using the alpine as the base image using this command:

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t="reddwarf-pro/reddwarf-admin:v.1.0.0" .
```

show error like this:

```
#14 222.9   = note: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../aarch64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
#14 222.9           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#14 222.9
#14 222.9
#14 223.0 warning: `reddwarf-admin` (bin "reddwarf-admin") generated 1 warning
#14 223.0 error: could not compile `reddwarf-admin` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo build --release]: exit code: 101
```

I have already add the `libpq` in the alpine image, why still show this error? what should I do to fix this problem? This is the Dockerfile:

```
# to reduce the docker image size
# build stage
FROM rust:1.54-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN rustup default stable
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libpq musl-dev pkgconfig openssl-dev gcc
RUN cargo build --release
# RUN cargo build

# Prod stage
FROM alpine:3.15
WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
# ENV ROCKET_PORT=11014
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libpq curl
COPY --from=builder /app/.env /app
COPY --from=builder /app/settings.toml /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/reddwarf-admin /app/
COPY --from=builder /app/Rocket.toml /app
CMD ["./reddwarf-admin"]
```

I am also tried to add `libpq-dev` but it seems the alpine did not contains this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps slightly confusingly, the dev version is called `postgresql-dev` and not `libpq-dev` in v3.14. (From what I can tell, it was renamed `libpq-dev` in v3.15).

`libpq` does indeed install the shared library, but `postgresql-dev` creates the symbolic link `/usr/lib/libpq.so -> libpq.so.5.13` which makes linking succeed.

From `man ld`:

> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also
> search for files other than libnamespec.a.  Specifically, on
> ELF and SunOS systems, ld will search a directory for a
> library called libnamespec.so before searching for one
> called libnamespec.a.  (By convention, a ".so" extension
> indicates a shared library.)  Note that this behavior does
> not apply to :filename, which always specifies a file called
> filename.

That is, the `-lname` syntax will only search for `libname.(a|so)`, not versioned names.

Answer (score -1):

The dependency you need is:

`libpq-dev`

Comment: I have already tried `libpq-dev`. @Sergio Santiago

Comment: Yeap looks like the answer sent by @frippe is correct

Comment: As far as I can tell, the name seems to have changed from `postgresql-dev` to `ibpq-dev` in `v3.15`, so ,technically, this answer is more up-to-date. However, since OP is using an image with version ID 3.14.2, it's still named `postgresql-dev`.